# Naming a baby after a living non-relative

Tags: minhag, names, family-members, ashkenazi, baby-infant

As an Ashkenazi Jew, can I name my child after someone who is alive if they are not a relative or are you not supposed to name a child after the living, regardless of your relationship with them or their religion?

Comment: CFN, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I hope you'll also look around and find other posts that interest you, perhaps including our 250+ other [tag:names] questions.

Comment: Not exactly a strong proof, but didn't the proliferation of Chaya Mushkas and Menachem Mendels in Chabad begin in earnest only after their respective deaths?

Answer (score 1):

There are certain circumstances where an Ashkenazi can name after a living person. They are discussed [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/820540/jewish/Can-a-Child-Be-Named-After-a-Living-Person.htm). Most notably is naming after a living righteous individual or Torah scholar. That source also says if the person gives explicit permission, it would be allowed, but it doesn't source the claim (the author is a Rabbi, however) and that one was new to me, so I would encourage you to double check it.

As always, CYLOR.